# .Net Core 2.1 identity Server using relative path for host and resources

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

We ran into a problem using the .Net Core 2.1 Identity Server with OpenIdConnect. Our environment is a multi resource landscape and one centralized authorization server. All resources including the authorization server are accessible over a local nginx with default configuration.

For examle:

- http://localhost/authserver
- http://localhost/resource1
- http://localhost/resource2

The problem occurred, while an unauthorized resource owner is redirected to the login page of the authorization provider, using the authorization code flow. When login with credentials and they are valid, the authorization server calls

- http://localhost/connect/authorize/callback? and should normally http://localhost/***resource1***/connect/authorize?

We are using the default configuration of the .net Core Identity Server.
We found a workarount using a subdomain for localhost, so the path is correct, but ran into another problem, executing the final resource callback.

The resource callback for the client is defined as http://localhost/resource1/callback, but this callback path is not set for the resource, so the callback turns into a 404 status.

```
authenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{                    
    o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.ClientId = myClient;
    o.ClientSecret = mySecret;
    o.CallbackPath = new PathString(/callback or absolute url); ;
    o.Authority = http://localhost/authserver;                    
    o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    o.SaveTokens = true;
    o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
        {
            c.HandleResponse();

            c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            return c.Response.WriteAsync("An error occurred processing your authentication.");
        }
    };
    o.Scope.Remove("profile");
});
```

The login in account controller of the authorization server is defined as follow:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
{
    var authorizationContext = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManagementApi.LoginAsync(
            new Credentials() {
                Email = model.Username,
                Password = model.Password
            }.ToViewModel()
        );

        if (user != null)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                new Claim("sub", user.Id.ToString()),
            };

            AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties
            {                        
                IsPersistent = false,
            };                   

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.Email, props, claims.ToArray());

            if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            }
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }

    return View(new LoginViewModel
    {
        Username = model.Username,
        Password = model.Password,
        ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl,
        RememberLogin = model.RememberLogin,
        ExternalProviders = new List<ExternalProvider>()
    });
}
```

This should be the default login.

Are there any configurations to solve the problem on the resource side and the authorization server side, or do we need to work with the workaround using subdomains for all our resources behind the nginx.

The whole setup works without problems, if we don't use the nginx and just work with the resources directly.